# Windows 2012 RDS Temporary profile for Administrator

Tags: windows-server-2012, rds

I've configured a Windows 2012 RDS Farm with two virtual servers (VMWare - each one on a different ESX server).

Both servers have Licensing, Web Access, Gateway, Connection Broker and Session Host roles. 
High Availability is set up and it works fine. 
Remote Apps are working and even Windows XP clients have access to the web interface. 
User profile path is \vmfiles1\UserProfileDisks\App\ and almost everyone has full right access to it.

The problem I have is that I would like to be able to access both servers at the same time with the Administrator account (console), but each time I try, the second server that I logon to give me access with a temporary profile. 
I tried to enable/disable multiple sessions per user and forced Admin logoff with the GPO but nothing changed.

Another thing is that the server pool is not saved, so each time I restart the RDS server or I logoff from it, I have to add a server in the server manager.

Do you have any idea?

Sorry if my english is not perfect.

[...]

Basically the main problem is: 
when profile disk is enabled, I can't connect with Administrator to both server at same time, because of course the Admin's profile disk is already in use. 
So I would like to know if is it possible to keep Profile Disk Enabled for the users and disabled for the Administrator. Is that possible?

Comment: On your second session, did you verify the computer you are logged on to by viewing the %COMPUTERNAME% variable?

Comment: yep I connect to the right server (%computername% gives me the right name, but I've also created an empty folder called with the server name on c:\  ) but each time I login, the first server I go into has the normal profile, the second one has a temporary profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is NO: I cannot disable user profile disks just for the Administrator, even if the user is not declared in the "User Groups" in the collection properties, because User Profile Disks (if I'm not wrong) is a Computer policy so there's no way to enable it only for certain users.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using User Profile Disks, you cannot log in with the same user account twice. The first session locks your profile on the UPD, so you naturally get a temp profile on your second login. There is no fix for this....it's normal behavior of UPD.

Answer (score 0):

Something I have seen to fix temporary profiles in the past is to delete the registry entry for the profile and let it recreate, not sure if this works the same way for RDS/Terminal Servers.  The fix I've used with high success is: Locate the following registry subkey:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList

Under the ProfileList subkey, delete the subkey that is named SID.bak (and SID without .bak assuming you've backed up the profile data elsewhere or don't care about it)  Hope that helps.

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947242

Comment: yep already tried this, but it didn't work... is like windows doesn't allow administrator to open 2 times the same profile on two different computers.On the server2 taskbar I've a toolbar with the name of the computer on it. when I login into the server1 (and I've a normal profile) I still see the taskbar with "server2" on it.