# User Profile Disks with RemoteApp 2012 R2 Locked

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, roaming-profile, rds

We have a RemoteApp deployment (Web, Gateway, High Available Connection Brokers, ...). We use profile disks stored on a file share.  We publish most of our applications, but from time to time, a user needs a full fletched desktop.

That's why we also published `mstsc` with the path to the original .rdp-file from when there were no applications published.

This all works fine, unless a user has an application open when they open the desktop.
The server fails to mount their profile disk (because it's already mounted by the session providing the application and thus locked).

This causes the session host to load a temporary profile.

Is there any way around this, while still using User Profile Disks?
Is it possible to get the session that is providing the apps when opening the desktop somehow?

Answer (score 1):

This question has come up previously ([Windows 2012 RDS Temporary profile for Administrator](https://serverfault.com/questions/601238)) with no workaround. UPD was only designed to support a single session per user.

Even if you could get the RemoteApp session, which I don't believe you can, the screen resolution would end up being very screwy, since it's based on the size of the single application window.

Your best bet is simple user education, or write some kind of script that's launched when they try to enter a full-desktop session to kick any other sessions off first.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @tfrederick74656,

> UPD was only designed to support a single session per user, *per session collection*

Best I've come up with is to provide users two session collections, both with their own UPD's. Use identical syspreps of Session Hosts across farm so the user experience is the same:

- Collection 1: RemoteApp's, published to RDWeb
- Collection 2: "Full Desktop", published to RDWeb

The full desktop can only be published if you don't create any Published Applications in the collection. It's an either-or scenario.

Only down side is twice as many UPD's and Session Hosts.